# Is it possible to use C# 9 for Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Officially, C# 9 only supports .NET 5. What about Xamarin? Is there an unofficial way to use C# 9 in Xamarin? What about libraries? Does it mean that any library that wants to support Xamarin cannot use C# 9?

EDIT:

- What are the recommended practices for library developers to use C# 9 and support Xamarin?
- Does Xamarin enabled libraries should target .NET Standard 2.1?
- What features of C# 9 are not available to Xamarin { Android / iOS } / .NET Standard 2.1 / .NET Framework (legacy)?

Comment: Last time I checked, you can only use C# 8 with Xamarin with the latest VS19. Checked on Version 16.7.7. Also checked [VS release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview). Didn't find anything related though!

Comment: See link above for Developers Community at bottom of page.  Be careful with forward/backwards compatibility.  which means for the most part (except bugs) C# 9 should work with C# 8 if you are using the compatible libraries.  In VS you can target different older versions so latest VS should work with older devices if the target is set properly.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, we can do it by using latest Visual studio (which supports .NET 5.0) and changing language version of project.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
        <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
    .....
    .....
</Project>
```